# Wildcard IP Banning with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement an IP banning system into my web app using MySQL, i know i can do it using `.htaccess` but that's not neat to me.

Basically my current table is:

```
ip_blacklist(id, ip, date)
```

and in php i look up the database for the client IP to see if it's blocked or not:

```
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM ip_blacklist WHERE ip = ? LIMIT 1"
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($ip));
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
 // Gotcha
}
```

Now.. this is working fine, but i want to be able to enter wildcard IP ranges in the database like:

```
42.21.58.*
42.21.*.*
53.*.*.*
```

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you will always be checking one IP address at a time **and** your banned ranges never intersect, you should store the start and end addresses of the ranges to ban in numeric format.

Say, you want to ban `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.15` which is `192.168.1.0/28`.

You create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ban (start_ip INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, end_ip INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL)
```

, insert the range there:

```
INSERT
INTO    ban
VALUES  (INET_ATON('192.168.1.0'), INET_ATON('192.168.1.0') + POWER(2, 32 - 28) - 1)
```

then check:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  end_ip
        FROM    ban
        WHERE   start_ip <= INET_ATON('192.168.1.14')
        ORDER BY
                start_ip DESC
        LIMIT 1
        ) >= INET_ATON('192.168.1.14')
```

The `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` parts are required for the query to be efficient.

This, as was stated before, assumes non-intersecting blocks and one IP at a time.

If the blocks intersect (for instance, you ban `192.168.1.0/28` and `192.168.1.0/24` at the same time), the query may return false negatives.

If you are want to query more than one IP at a time (say, update a table with a long list of IP addresses), then this query will be inefficient (`MySQL` does not optimize `range` in correlated subqueries well)

In both these cases, you should need to store your ranges as `LineString` and use spatial indexes for fast searches:

```
CREATE TABLE ban (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, range LINESTRING NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sx_ban_range ON ban (range);

INSERT
INTO    ban (range)
VALUES  (
        LineString
                (
                Point(INET_ATON('192.168.1.0'), -1),
                Point(INET_ATON('192.168.1.0') + POWER(2, 32 - 28) - 1), 1)
                )
        );

SELECT  *
FROM    ban
WHERE   MBRContains(range, Point(INET_ATON('192.168.1.14'), 0))
```

Comment: Here we see Quassnoi embodying the voice of experience.  If you're not storing your IPs in a numeric format, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is trickier if you want to ban subnets

Notes:

- A "wildcard" mapping should use 0 (eg 42.21.58.0) which defines that subnet
- the .0 may not be the subnet because of CIDR (could .128, .192 etc)

So:

- Store IP as a 4 byte binary or unsigned int
- Store the subnet mask as a binary (or uint) 4 for subnet blacklisting
- Look at [INET_NTOA and INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) for translating IP addresses

Then the WHERE clause becomes

```
WHERE ip = @ip   --whole IP
      OR
      (ip & mask = @ip) --subnet
```

If you make the mask `0xffffffff` for exact IP addresses then you can always do `ip & mask = @ip`, with `ip & mask` as a computed column

Also, you have IPv6 to think of too

Comment: Thanks for that, i don't know much about IP's but what is subnet marking for? and how to store the IP as a 4byte binary?

Comment: @David: I'd start poking around on Wikipedia eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR. And I just updaed with the MySQL functions to use

Comment: i'm pretty sure experts here understand your solution, but for me and other beginners it's little vague :/ could you give a quick php example of how to convert the IP to the format which your SQL accepts?

Comment: @David: I don't write php. Have a look at my links for the MySQL function INET_ATON that does some of this for you. I had a look at other MySQL IP blacklist solutions and they *don't* support wildcards hence the complexity of this solution to correct this deficiency

Comment: @David, when you do implement this, keep in mind that you won't actually know the remote subnet mask.  You should support banning by it though in your application.

Comment: @Brad: Thanks, in which case there are several solutions already: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=store+IP+blacklist+in+a+database

Answer (score 2):

Quick'n'Dirty, but cannot use proper indexes:

```
SELECT ip FROM ip_blacklist WHERE ? LIKE REPLACE(ip,'*','%') LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hmm. Actually the `?` would be the client's IP and won't contain stars

Comment: The idea is good. Just exchange the **ip** with **?** and voila! :)

Comment: Ah, damn, missed that, fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion might make some cringe, but you seem to be going for nontraditional in this project so here it goes:
Parse each IP from the database into a regex that can be compared against the user's IP. Example:

```
<?php
//Fetch IP's and begin to contruct regex
$regex = array();
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $regex[] = '('.$arr['ip'].')';
}

$regex = implode('|', $regex); //Regex now becomes (1.1.1.1)|(2.2.2.2)|etc.
$regex = str_replace('.', '\.', $regex); //Escape dots for regex
$regex = str_replace('*', '((25[0-5])|(2[0-4]\d)|(1\d\d)|(\d\d?))', $regex); //Deal with wildcards

$httpVars = array( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
foreach( $httpVars as $httpVar ) {  //No hiding behind proxies
    if( isset( $IP = $_SERVER[$httpVar] ) ) {
        break;
    }
}

if(preg_match('/^'.$regex.'$/', $IP) != 0) {
    die(header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'));  //Magical regex says user should be banned
}
?>
```

And of course you can do much more with this. You could cache the regex to save querying the database on every request or even expand your wild card options to includes IP ranges.

Answer (score 0):

convert wildcards from `42.21.*.*` to `42.21.0.0` and back when writing or reading entries from database. For efficiency (low memory and disk footprint, performance) store it as an integer, use [INET_NTOA and INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) for conversion.

when you look up an IP address a.b.c.d:

```
SELECT ip FROM ip_blacklist WHERE ip=INET_ATON('a.b.c.d') or ip=INET_ATON('a.b.c.0') or ip=INET_ATON('a.b.0.0') or ip=INET_ATON('a.0.0.0')
```

Ok, the last match is probably *silly*.

Don't forget to add indexes.